# Meaning of 'on' in "We feasted that evening as 'on' nectar and ambrosia"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “I meant to give each of you some of this to take with you,” said she,
>   “but as there is so little toast, you must have it now,” and she
>   proceeded to cut slices with a generous hand. 
> We feasted that evening
>   as **on** nectar and ambrosia; and not the least delight of the
>   entertainment was the smile of gratification with which our hostess
>   regarded us, as we satisfied our famished appetites on the delicate
>   fare she liberally supplied. (Jane Eyre)

What’s the meaning of ‘on’?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the key word here is **as**, actually.  The word **as** lets you know that it's a simile; the word **on** is just the preposition in the phrase "feast on [something]".

It means the same thing as if these words were inserted:

> We feasted [on the food we had] that evening as [we would] on nectar and ambrosia [...]

Comment: +1, but I think your example would be better and less ambiguous if your example were "We feasted [on the food we had] that evening **in the same way that** [we would **have feasted**] on nectar and ambrosia [...]"

Answer (score 7):

I would paraphrase it like this:

> *We feasted that evening as if we were having nectar and ambrosia*.

It helps to know what nectar and ambrosia are; from NOAD:

> **ambrosia** (*noun*) [*Greek & Roman Mythology*] the food of the gods
>
> **nectar** (*noun*) [*Greek & Roman Mythology*] the drink of the gods

The sentence means that, whatever they ate and drank that evening, it was particularly exotic or satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

> Feast on food = eat food

On is just a preposition that follows feast when it is used as a verb.